# 404 Error after Deleting Content Database (With no Site Collections)?

Tags: 2010, site, 404, content-database, site-collection

After detaching a database in SharePoint then subsequently deleting in SQL Server I have been getting 404 Errors at my root site collection default.aspx page, and a few other random site collections for some strange reason, I should note that:

A) That root site collection never was even on my content database that I deleted
B) Site collections that were on that content database, but were moved onto other content databases still are functioning normally.
C) This was the "Original" Content database, it spun up with the web application but was to be phased out for better database servers.  We had been moving everyone off to different databases.

This is completely bizzarre.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting 404 messages with SharePoint in general will likely be appreciated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we figured it out...for some reason some publish data was removed and a check-out/check-in of the default.aspx file fixed the problem.  We have a solution but I'm now extremely curious as to underlying cause...